# Displaying Bitmap Image from Database into GridView with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I am currently trying to display the a QR code bitmap image that is being stored as varbinary in the SQL database into a gridview, and I have referred to this link: [https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-images-from-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASP.Net-GridView-control.aspx]

However, I am unable to display the image properly in the gridview table and I couldn't seem to figure out the error with it.

This is my code for the gridview code behind:

```
      if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM PARCEL", conn))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind(); 
                }
            }
        }

        protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
                string imageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])dr["QRCode"]);
                (e.Row.FindControl("QRCode") as Image).ImageUrl = imageUrl;
            }
        }
```

The markup for gridview:

```
<asp:GridView 
        ID="GridView1" 
        runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ConsignmentNumber" 
        AllowPaging="True" 
        HorizontalAlign="Center" 
        ViewStateMode="Enabled">

        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ConsignmentNumber" HeaderText="ConsignmentNumber" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ConsignmentNumber" /> 
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="QRCode" runat="server" HeaderText="QRCode" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
           
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I would like to know if there is any solution or suggestion that I can apply in order to display the images properly.

Comment: What is the current problem excactly? Do you receive an error in your c# code or in your browser? Is it compiling?

Comment: And is it intentional, that you are not binding your data in `GridView1.DataSource=...` by commenting your code out?

Comment: @Marco yes it is compiling, and no error code is given at all in both c# code and browser. It's just that the image is not displaying at all in the gridview.

Comment: Your Databind method is commented out - if you do not bind the data, it will not render any data and thus the OnRowbound event will never fire.

Comment: @Marco sorry for the confusion, I have edited my post. i wasn't supposed to comment that out. I have removed the comment yet it still isn't displaying the image properly

Comment: But the error you now have in your question comes when you visit your page yes?

Comment: @Marco yes it only now appears in the C# code when i run it.

Comment: is the QRCode column in SQL actually called `QRCode`? using select * is considered a smell and it is wise to avoid it.

Comment: @Marco yes it is called ```QRCode``` in the SQL too. what do you mean by it is considered as a smell? And how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error you are experiencing, you have defined a `DataSourceId` in your markup AND are setting the datasource in codebehind. You can do either, but not both. That is what the error is telling you.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="yourdatasource">
    <Columns>
       <!-- ... -->
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Find the `DataSourceID` in your markup and remove it, as you are setting it in your code-behind cs file:

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have removed the repeating DataSourceId in my markup and the only datasource left now is in codebehind. It is now running without any error, yet the images are still not displaying.

Comment: Please set a breakpoint in your `OnRowDataBound` and check whether the QRCode column of your datatable is actually filled with data. If that is the case, check your browser console (f12) for errors. Please also add your GridView markup your to question.

Comment: i have added the GridView markup code to the question.